# How to export to a dataframe results from emmeans contrast()?

Tags: r, dataframe, export, emmeans

After running the test (`model1.emm=emmeans(model1,~timeBin)
contrast(model1.emm, "trt.vs.ctrl", ref = 1,  adjust='fdr')`), here is what I see in Console:
[image]

Would it be possible to export this output to a dataframe?

I learned how to export the rest of the results:
`result = as.data.frame(summary(model1.emm))`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Export it the same way. The result of `contrast()` is an `emmGrid` object, the same class as from `emmeans()`. You may use `summary()` or `as.data.frame()` — no need to use both.